# preg_match get contents of variable

Tags: javascript, php, curl, preg-match, screen-scraping

I currently have a PHP preg_match and cURL script that gets the content of a specific line and displays it.

http://cdadownloader.cf is the link. If you will paste in the form e.g 5640653 it will scrape the content of http://www.cda.pl/video/5640653, then the preg_match

```
 preg_match_all("~^\s*file\s*:\s*'(.*?)',?\s*$~m", $source_code, $file);
```

will look inside the script tags for a line called " file "

```
file: 'http://vgra012.cda.pl/13495603584734.flv?st=s5O2O-YWjbPgOLS3GLGHGg&e=1453683496',
```

and will get is contents in this case

```
 http://vgra009.cda.pl/13495603584734.flv?st=Vu78-g3noIN23uy_9-mKZQ&e=1453683460
```

by using

```
substr($file[0][0], 23,-2)
```

the URL is displayed and used.

Everything works fine ( download buttons does not work as i still have a problem with headers so only works with right click to save )

now they have added a premium player that uses a variable to store the url and i have no idea how to get its contents

```
$f().setClip('http://vrbx098.cda.pl/vl73f1740f66221a2168a374b86409140d.mp4?st=D-wuSToxZfD4e4UGaXw4qg&e=1453679326');
```

Would someone be able to point me in the right direction without unnecessary comments ? :) Thanks in Advance

Comment: how did you get this line: `$f().setClip('http://vrbx098.cda.pl/vl73f1740f66221a2168a374b86409140d.mp4?st=D-wuSToxZfD4e4UGaXw4qg&e=1453679326');` ? what does `setClip` method do?

Comment: Ok. If you will go to the cda url i have provided and browse the source code for .mp4 you will see the line i am already scraping with success. Now if you will go to the premium player http://cda.pl/video/520973f5 and do the same with the source code which means search for the .mp4 bit in the sourcee code this is where you will get it from. Makes sense ?

Comment: It probides the url to the video

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to do?  I'm confused.  You need the text of the URL `http://vrbx098....`?

Comment: I need a preg match to scrape contents of $f().setClip('http://vrbx098.cda.pl/vl73f1740f66221a2168a374b86409140d.mp4?st=D‌​-wuSToxZfD4e4UGaXw4qg&e=1453679326');

Comment: In between the ('this')

Comment: So you want me to show you how to pull the URL out of there?  (Sorry if I'm being slow here.  I just am having trouble understanding what it is that you are wanting.)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I understand what you are wanting.  Here is something for you to try:

```
preg_match("~setClip\('(.*?)'~", $page_contents, $setclip_match);
$setclip_url = $setclip_match[1];
```